# Using Guice with a custom class?

Tags: java, guice

I'm working with a Guice enabled framework.

When using classes that were created by the framework (or subclasses that override existing bindings), I can instantiate framework provided variables very easily.  Whatever I need, it's just a matter of

```
@Inject
FrameworkProvidedType variable;
```

However, in my custom created classes, that doesn't work.  All of the injected variables are null.

It's my *understanding* that in order to use injection, my class has to have a binding.

If I'm subclassing an existing framework class, I can override the binding in my module class.  That's pretty straightforward.

But I have a new class and I don't know how to bind it to the underlying framework.

```
public Class myCustomClass {

   private String iNeedthis;
   private Context thisToo;

   @Inject
   FrameWorkThing magic;

   public myCustomClass(String iNeedThis, Context thisToo){
         this.iNeedThis = iNeedThis;
         this.thisToo = thisToo;
   }

   public void DoMagic(){
        //null pointer error because magic was not injected
        magic.doMagic(this.iNeedthis);
   }
}
```

How do I Guice-enable this new class?

I tried this in my Runtime Module

```
public Class<myCustomClass> bindMyCustomClass(){
    return MyCustomClass.class;
}
```

and failed miserably.

Comment: What about reading the (really rather good) [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/GettingStarted)?

Comment: I tried that and didn't understand it - not how that page (or any other within the documentation) applies to the situation described in my question.  But thanks for ensuring that nobody else will answer my question by downvoting it right out of the gate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No thanks to @bmorris591 who dismissed and downvoted the question out of the gate, I found an answer.

@Inject-ing a field into a class means that the class instance needs to be created by Guice.

Step 1 is creating a factory for the class.  This may not be necessary, but it worked for me.

```
public interface MyCustomClassFactory {
    public MyCustomClass create(String iNeedThis, Context thisToo);
}
```

Step 2 is installing the factory into Guice

```
@Override
public void configure(Binder binder) {

    super.configure(binder);

    binder.install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(MyCustomClass.class));
}
```

In my particular case - the framework I'm working with provides a Module class that is an implementation of com.google.inject.Module.

Within that class is a "configure(Binder binder)" function that is called on startup.

Step 3 is actually annotating the constructor

```
@Inject
public myCustomClass(String iNeedThis, Context thisToo){
     this.iNeedThis = iNeedThis;
     this.thisToo = thisToo;
}
```

Useful and related web page that put me on the right track:

http://beust.com/weblog/2012/08/21/advanced-dependency-injection-with-guice/

This talks about assisted injection, but it gave enough information and a simple enough to understand example that taking the next step was pretty easy.